# UIPopoverController changes size in ios 8 when alert view is shown

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uipopovercontroller, uialertcontroller

I hava popovercontroller visible on my view controller and its size is fine and everything runs ok.
But as soon as I press a row in it and a UIAlertController is shown then the popover changes size and is disfigured.This happens only in ios 8. Please see the images attached.

[image: Pop over in normal size]

[image: Distorted popover]

**@UPDATE**
This only happens for popovers with size less than 270 in width.

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8 and might have unexpected behavior. Use UIAlertController instead and see if you face the same issue.

Comment: @gagarwal I am using UIAlertController, sorry for confusion.

Comment: Could you paste us the code you are using to display the alert message? And from where are you calling the alert view?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to display the AlertViewController from within the UIPopoverController by specifying the AlertViewController's sourceView and sourceRect.

```
alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = selectedCell?.contentView
alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = selectedCell!.contentView.frame
```